# find the packet loss rate in mosquitto mqtt

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I want to use the mqtt message broker mosquitto to receive the value of each sensor to the Raspberry Pi and to monitor the message delivery success rate of each sensor. In order to obtain this information, we need to calculate the packet loss rate. Can I get the information from within mosquitto?

Comment: You are going to have to supply some more detail here about exactly what you want to measure here, but since MQTT normally runs of TCP/IP then any packet loss will be handled by the TCP stack before it ever gets near to mosquitto.  Also what QOS are you planning to use?

Comment: What I want to measure is the voltage value of the smartPlug that supports mqtt communication and I want to know the amount of packet loss to monitor the transmission status of the smartPlug. QOS uses mode 1 to reduce the amount of loss.

Comment: I think comparing the amount of traffic on the tcp/ip layer gives you an idea of ​​the loss, but I don't think smartPlug can measure the amount of traffic on the tcp/ip layer, so it would be better to do something like this: It could only be measured by mosquitto.

Comment: As a result of searching the documentation of mosquitto, there was a command to know the amount of incoming and outgoing data of the broker. 
"$SYS/broker/messages/received"
"$SYS/broker/messages/sent"
I thought about using this command, but I realized that it is difficult to use it in a situation where you need to know the loss rate for each topic because it checks the amount of data sent and received by the entire broker. Is it possible to check the amount of data sent and received by topic?

Comment: But when reading from a socket in C you don't get any indication if the TCP/IP stack has triggered a retransmission, the application layer only sees the data that arrives, with no information about what was dropped/lost. The only way to measure packet loss is to measure the network at both ends of the connection and compare.